# Security Header in Android ksoap

Tags: java, android, web-services, security

I am working on android application in which i want to make my User and password of Webservices in security header. I just follow one of the post from stackoverflow and make a header request in android side. It is working fine and i am able to send my reuqest with security headers. I created sample code at server side which will check user and password. Without using secuirty headers my request still works. I want to know that how can i use security headers,like without security headers i should not be able to send request. My code for service and android is given below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://test.android.com";
    private final String URL = "http://192.168.1.107:8080/WebServiceProject/services/PrintTest?wsdl";//
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://test.android.com/login";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "login";//"CallWebServiceImpl";//
    private static String cityNames ;

    String userName;
    String password;

    EditText userText;
    EditText passText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        userText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        passText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
            finish();
        }

        Button signIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signInBtn);
        signIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            {
                userName= userText.getText().toString();
                password= passText.getText().toString();
                getSignIn(userName,password);
            }
            }
            });

    }
    public void getSignIn(String user, String Pass) {
        //Create request

        if(userName.length()==0&&password.length()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Kindly fill the fields first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
        }else{


            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            PropertyInfo celsiusPI = new PropertyInfo();
            celsiusPI.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty("user",userName);
            request.addProperty("pass",password);


            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);


            // create header
            Element[] header = new Element[1];
            header[0] = new Element().createElement("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd","Security");
            header[0].setAttribute(null, "mustUnderstand","1");

            Element usernametoken = new Element().createElement("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "UsernameToken");
            usernametoken.setAttribute(null, "Id", "UsernameToken-1");
            header[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT,usernametoken);

            Element username = new Element().createElement(null, "n0:Username");
            username.addChild(Node.IGNORABLE_WHITESPACE,"CBROWN");
            usernametoken.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,username);

            Element pass = new Element().createElement(null,"n0:Password");
            pass.setAttribute(null, "Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
            pass.addChild(Node.TEXT, "welcome");

            usernametoken.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, pass);

            // add header to envelope
            envelope.headerOut = header;
            envelope.dotNet = false;
            envelope.bodyOut = request;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

         HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
         androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();


            if(response.equals(null)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Host Not Responding", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Pin Combination", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
}
```

// For Web Service

```
 package com.android.test;
/*    */ 
/*    */ public class PrintTest
/*    */ {
/*    */   public String sayHello(String string)
/*    */   {
/*  6 */     return "Hello " + string;
/*    */   }
/*    */   
/*    */   public String login(String userName, String userPassword)
/*    */   {
/*    */     
/*    */    if(userName.equals("abc") & userPassword.equals("def")){

                return  userName+" is a valid user";
                }if(userName.equals("hij") & userPassword.equals("klm")){

                    return  userName+" is a valid user";
                    }
                else{

                    return  userName+" is not a valid user";    

                }


/*    */   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me to give the Security Request Header in kSOAP library in Android

This is SOAP Envelop Request Header:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cif="http://www.mawarid.ae/linkedCardsSummary/CRM/CIF.xsd">
       <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-14CBAE357AC169AFA614664925178422">
            <wsse:Username>Mawarid</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">M@warid!23</wsse:Password>
                </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

Here is JAVA Android Code:

```
public static Element buildAuthHeader() {
        Element headers[] = new Element[1];
        headers[0]= new Element().createElement("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "Security");
        headers[0].setAttribute(null, "mustUnderstand", "1");
        Element security=headers[0];

        //user token
        Element usernametoken = new Element().createElement(security.getNamespace(), "UsernameToken");
        usernametoken.setAttribute("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd", "Id", "UsernameToken-14CBAE357AC169AFA614664925178422");

        //username
        Element username = new Element().createElement(security.getNamespace(), "Username");
        username.addChild(Node.TEXT, HttpConstant.REQ_HEADER_USERNAME);
        usernametoken.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,username);

        // password
        Element password = new Element().createElement(security.getNamespace(), "Password");
        password.setAttribute(null, "Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
        password.addChild(Node.TEXT, HttpConstant.REQ_HEADER_PASSWORD);
        usernametoken.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,password);


        headers[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT, usernametoken);



        return headers[0];
    }





SoapSerializationEnvelope sSerialaEnvelop = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        sSerialaEnvelop.dotNet = true;
        sSerialaEnvelop.headerOut = new Element[1];
        sSerialaEnvelop.headerOut[0] = buildAuthHeader(); //// add security request header
        sSerialaEnvelop.bodyOut = sObject;
        sSerialaEnvelop.setOutputSoapObject(sObject);
```